# Build package with CSS modules for Next.js

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, next.js

Building a package with UI components using CSS modules. Each component is totally separated from others and includes CSS styles like this:

```js
import css from './styles.css'

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div className={css.container}>Hello there!</div>
  )
}

export { SearchBar }
```

In another package based on Next.js I want import a component like this:

```
import { Component } from '@me/components'
```

But Next.js doesn't allow Module CSS import from node_modules.

My question is how can I build the component package with CSS transformed into JS. It shouldn't be merged into one file just like Webpack do. Instead it should build each component separately. Also I don't want to import a huge CSS files with all styles merged into single file. Easiest way would be to use CSS-in-JS, but I want to use PostCSS written in CSS files.

Comment: I am facing the similar issue

Comment: @Shubham Actually I ended up with styled-components and I have to say it was a great choice, it's like a pure CSS, but I have a freedom of using JS in it.

Comment: @ Jaroslav Zavodny but i need to override the some classes, do u know how we can do that without external css files.

Comment: @Shubham With styled components you can do whatever you want, you can even override existing classes (https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting)

Comment: can you please help me how can i override it.

Comment: @Shubham Please create a new question, describe a problem there and share a link here, I will answer it ASAP. I can't write a code here.